# What is expected from me when I have to reproduce a proof?

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

I have followed a few courses where I had to prove statements in math. You could say I am relatively new to proving in maths.

This is what I can and am comfortable with at this moment:

- proving statements by a chain of equal signs, for example: 
  $$\sin(x) = (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/(2i)$$
- proving statements by a chain of implication arrows, for example:
  (u and v are vectors) (the length of u+v)^2= (the length of u)^2 + 
  (the length of v)^2 implies the dot product of u and v = o

This is what I have difficulties with: we were given a list of proofs that we have to be able to reproduce, for example:
- an increasing sequence either converges or diverges
- every, bounded monotonic sequence is convergent

This is the problem/difficulty I have: the way this proof is conducted is not in the same manner as the ones I described. rather the proofs were pretty much all in words. I kind of do get what the content is of the proof, but if its expected from me that I have to reproduce them, does that mean I just have to memorize and kind of rewrite what is written in the slides/sheets of the professor. because that is really what reproducing is, since coming up with your own ideas/proofs is almost impossible for a first year student that is new to proving.

Comment: Yes, memory is a large part of the process of learning. Of course, instead of creating identical and isolated memories it is better to remember each idea connected to others, in different contexts, in slightly different forms. You can achieve this by seeing proofs by others, and eventually by you, that apply the same ideas.

Comment: By the way, all those proofs "all in words" can also be written as a single chain of implications. Lucky you that you don't have to see or write them in that way.

Comment: okay, what if they ask on the exam prove this statement and i rewrite exactly what i memorized from the slides, would that be correct?

Comment: @AlexYuen If it's a written exam, that should suffice. In an oral exam, you would probably be asked about details to see that you understand them.

Comment: Although the second comment of @OscarRascal is important, nonetheless I disagree with it somewhat. When memorizing a proof, you should not memorize the sequence of words, instead you should memorize the logical steps, which **are** expressed in the words. Those steps are not all just single implications; some of them might be forward implications, or backward implications; some of them might be formulas written down to demonstrate existence of something; and so on. Anyway, part of what you have to learn in reading proofs is how to re-express the words as precise logical steps.

Comment: Try to prove each theorem yourself, based on only definitions and previously proved theorems, and get for hint in the given wordy proof only if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: I wholly concur with Lee Mosher. You should not be memorizing words. You should be memorizing ideas. Read the proofs not with an idea of "do this, then do this, then do this", but rather asking yourself "is this convincing?" Does it make me believe the theorem is true? Can I figure out a way to avoid the logic of the proof and come up with a counter-example? Does it shut every avenue where the theorem might fail? How does it do that? Why does it make sense? Those are the things that will help you in proving. Memorizing proofs will only help you in remembering.

Comment: Don't vandalise posts.